# Bootstrap datepicker set half day

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Is it possible to set half day for bootstrap datepicker

and use different color for same date?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('page:change', function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            multidate: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            language: "ru",
            startDate: "today"
        });
    });
</script>
```